# Installing ftdichip D2XX Drivers (usb lib) on macos 10.14.2

Tags: macos, usb, drivers, macos-mojave

I've downloaded the 1.4.16 version of D2XX from [ftdichip](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) and followed the process (files to copy and symbolic link to create) and have also installed D2xxHelper.

Now on *System* → *Info* → *USB* I can see the driver:

[[image: USB system info screenshot]]

But running `make` in D2XX/SAMPL via Terminal doesn't work.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Christophe:Samples christophetroeira$ cd /Users/christophetroeira/Desktop/D2XX/Samples
MacBook-Pro-de-Christophe:Samples christophetroeira$ 
MacBook-Pro-de-Christophe:Samples christophetroeira$ make
for n in BitMode EEPROM/erase EEPROM/read EEPROM/write EEPROM/user/read EEPROM/user/size EEPROM/user/write Events LargeRead loopback MultiThread SetVIDPID Simple static Timeouts W32/escapeseq W32/events W32/simple W32/timeouts write ; do "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -C $n || exit 1; done
cc main.c -o bitmode-static ../../build/libftd2xx.a -Wall -Wextra -lpthread -lobjc -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation
clang: error: no such file or directory: '../../build/libftd2xx.a'
make[1]: *** [bitmode-static] Error 1
make: *** [subdirs] Error 1
```

I want to use the driver with Lxnet2OpenDMX which still says that it needs the D2XX driver.

Lxnet2OpenDMX reads Artnet input (from LXConsole software) and outputs to USB/DMX device (Enttec Open DMW USB)

Answer (score 2):

OK, a more complete version of the answer is that the make command will not work unless you add a directory named "build" to the D2XX directory, and *then* add a copy of the file "libftd2xx.a" to that build directory.  After that, make works properly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the no such file in directory error by creating a folder named build in the D2XX directory. It seems that the build folder was removed, but the makefile was not updated.